# Adding self starting values to an nls regression in R

Tags: r, regression, sigmoid

I have existing code for fitting a sigmoid curve to data in R. How can I used selfstart (or another method) to automatically find start values for the regression?

```
sigmoid = function(params, x) {
  params[1] / (1 + exp(-params[2] * (x - params[3])))
}

dataset = data.frame("x" = 1:53, "y" =c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.68,0.58,0.58,0.68,0.83,0.83,0.83,0.74,0.74,0.74,0.83,0.83,0.9,0.9,0.9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) )

x = dataset$x
y = dataset$y

# fitting code
fitmodel <- nls(y~a/(1 + exp(-b * (x-c))), start=list(a=1,b=.5,c=25))

# visualization code
# get the coefficients using the coef function
params=coef(fitmodel)

y2 <- sigmoid(params,x)
plot(y2,type="l")
points(y)
```

Comment: A simple two-parameter Inverse Exponential equation, "y = a * exp(b/x)" appears to give a good fit to the data, with parameters a = 2.2757248107168646E+00 and b = -4.1867657807394536E+01 yielding RMSE = 0.0504 and R-squared = 0.980.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common (and interesting) problem in non-linear curve fitting.

### Background

We can find sensible starting values if we take a closer look at the function `sigmoid`

[image]

We first note that

[image]

So for large values of `x`, the function approaches `a`. In other words, as a starting value for `a` we may choose the value of `y` for the *largest* value of `x`.
In R language, this translates to `y[which.max(x)]`.

Now that we have a starting value for `a`, we need to decide on starting values for `b` and `c`. To do that, we can make use of the geometric series

[image]

and expand `f(x) = y` by keeping only the first two terms

[image]

We now set `a = 1` (our starting value for `a`), re-arrange the equation and take the logarithm on both sides

[image]

We can now fit a linear model of the form `log(1 - y) ~ x` to obtain estimates for the slope and offset, which in turn provide the starting values for `b` and `c`.

### R implementation

Let's define a function that takes as an argument the values `x` and `y` and returns a `list` of parameter starting values

```
start_val_sigmoid <- function(x, y) {
    fit <- lm(log(y[which.max(x)] - y + 1e-6) ~ x)
    list(
        a = y[which.max(x)],
        b = unname(-coef(fit)[2]),
        c = unname(-coef(fit)[1] / coef(fit)[2]))
}
```

Based on the data for `x` and `y` you give, we obtain the following starting values

```
start_val_sigmoid(x, y)
#$a
#[1] 1
#
#$b
#[1] 0.2027444
#
#$c
#[1] 15.01613
```

Since `start_val_sigmoid` returns a `list` we can use its output directly as the `start` argument in `nls`

```
nls(y ~ a / ( 1 + exp(-b * (x - c))), start = start_val_sigmoid(x, y))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ a/(1 + exp(-b * (x - c)))
#   data: parent.frame()
#      a       b       c
# 1.0395  0.1254 29.1725
# residual sum-of-squares: 0.2119
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 9
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.373e-06
```

---

### Sample data

```
dataset = data.frame("x" = 1:53, "y" =c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.41,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.68,0.58,0.58,0.68,0.83,0.83,0.83,0.74,0.74,0.74,0.83,0.83,0.9,0.9,0.9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) )

x = dataset$x
y = dataset$y
```

Comment: You're very welcome @Andrew; please note that I fixed a typo/mistake in `start_val_sigmoid` where the linear model should be generally `log(y[which.max(x)] - y + 1e-6) ~ x`; it doesn't change anything, as in this example `y[which.max(x)]` equals 1, so the code I gave earlier was specific for the `x`, `y` sample data.